# how does this for loop work ? what is its purpose?

Tags: loops, for-loop

I am new to programming and i have never come across through such a for loop. The last time I used a for loop looked like `for(I = 0, I<=x.length(); I++)`.... so I'm trying to find out what " : " does in this loop.

code:

```
for (Cell cell : cl.board){    
    if(cell instanceof Ladder)
    ladders++;
    else if (cell instanceof Chute)
    chutes++;
 }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted what language this is.  Is it Java?

Comment: i think/guess cl.board contains array/list of cell object cell could be a base class of ladder and chute . if cell is object type ladder increment ladder , if it is type chute increment chute

Answer (score 1):

It is called an "enhanced" for loop in java. Also a "for each" loop.

```
for(Cell c:board){
  // do something
}
```

is read as "For each element `c` (which is a `Cell`) in `board`"

The equivalent is:

```
for(int i=0;i<board.length;i++){ // assuming board is an array
    Cell c = board[i];
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify in which language that code is written. Anyway, assuming that is for example JAVA, I think you could take a look at http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a **foreach** loop. It means:

For each object of type **Cell** in the list-object **cl.board**, do the following:

**if(cell instanceof Ladder) ladders++; else if (cell instanceof Chute) chutes++;**

This only works if **cl.board** is a list of cells.

For more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a foreach loop. Instead of using index, it will get the children one by one from the set/array/map. If you dont need the index, you can just iterate the content by using `foreach`